# What is the Ternary Sequence™

Tags: pattern, number-sequence

The sequence below, I call the $\text{Ternary Sequence™}$.

> \begin{gather*}
> \text{T}(1) = 1\\
> \text{T}(2) = 2\\
> \text{T}(3) = 5\\
> \text{T}(4) = 5\\
> \text{T}(5) = 3\\
> \text{T}(6) = 5\\
> \text{T}(7) = 7\\
> \text{T}(8) = 14\\
> \text{T}(9) = \hspace{0.4em} \color{blue}{???}\\
> \text{T}(10) = 3\\
> \text{T}(11) = 4\\
> \text{T}(12) = 5\\
> \text{T}(13) = 25\\
> \text{T}(14) = 14\\
> \text{T}(15) = 15\\
> \dots
> \end{gather*}

The sequence continues infinitely.

**What is the pattern that these numbers follow?**

**What is $\text{T}(9)$?**

Comment: I like the fact that all your questions have TradeMark in them :P

Comment: @SagarChand It has been a trend for years before I joined. [Some examples](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+phrase+is%3Aquestion).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> $T(n)$ = Ternary ( $f(n)$ )

where

> $f(n)$ is minimum number $x$ formed with $0,1,2$ such that $n | x$.

By this logic T(9) is

> Ternary($12222$) = $161$

Comment: Hey, apologies if this question sounds naive, but how is T(3) = 5?
T(3) = Ternary(12) , then what?
Like how is Ternary(12222) = 161?

Comment: @SagarChand T(3) = 5 since the smallest decimal number consisting of only 0, 1, and 2 that is divisible by 3 is 12. If 12 were a number in base 3 (ternary), it would represent 5 in decimal ($1 \cdot 3^1 + 2 \cdot 3^0$). If 12222 were a ternary number, it would be 161 in decimal ($1 \cdot 3^4 + 2 \cdot 3^3 + 2 \cdot 3^2 + 2 \cdot 3^1 + 2 \cdot 3^0$).

Comment: @eyl327 got it now
thanks